# Joining table to feature class AND matching fields using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins

I am digitizing points from pdfs and aerial imagery.  Just points.  Then I want to create lots of fields and populate them without resorting to FieldCalculator or arcpy.DA modules.  There are too many fields and rows to add manually using FieldCalculator.  So here are my first steps:

1. create new feature class --> point
2. manually add (digitize) 30-40 points

Then I need to populate all 30 rows with 10 fields worth of values. So I am separately filling out a csv with 30 rows to join to those points.  For instance 30 features/points on new feature class gets 30 rows in a csv. The csv has 10 attribute fields and I fill out all the values for each of the 30 rows ON the CSV because it's fast and easy.  Next steps:
3. join the csv to the basically empty feature class
4. export the joined feature class

Then each week I digitize 40 new points in feature class and I need continue with the csv protocol and join.  So I tried:
5. edit existing feature and digitize the 30 new points
6. create new csv with id_join field matching the objectid of 30 new points in feature class (31-60 for example).

My problem is, apparently there is no capability to essentially join WHILE mapping the attributes from csv to the feature class.  For instance if field: **num_people** was created on first join and existed in feature class when second join occurs, I can't join my batch with rows 31-60 containing the EXACT same fields and field names and populate those fields from 31-60.  Brand new fields are created.

So it's basically a join/append hybrid I am trying to achieve to allow a periodic update of growing feature class.

Does anybody have a workflow preferably using joins or other tools in ArcMap?

Comment: Each week you need to create a brand new featureclass and populate with points, lets say 30 new points, then you join your updated CSV file to it with its 30 rows. Then export to a temporary featureclass to make the join permanent. Finally *append* this temporary dataset to your master dataset.

Comment: That is a solution.  I was hoping to not create new feature classes and just add.  I simplified my description to keep the question more straightforward.  I may add points 5 times in a day - 2 new points, and hour later 5 new points, an hour later 8 new points, etc.  That's why I was hoping to edit the existing feature instead of creating new ones each time.  But your overall approach is sound and certainly may be the solution I have to settle on...Thanks!

Comment: You could create a simple model that does the join, export and append so you don't have to keep running those tools independently. Model builder is ideal these sort of processing issues.